# Jmeter error:No valid credentials provided Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

when I am trying to run JMeter on On-premise for my application getting the error "NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))" Could anyone please suggest the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your application uses external authentication subsystem, in particular [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) so you need to add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to your Test Plan and provide your domain, realm and credentials there.

In addition you need to setup [jaas.conf](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jaas.conf) and [krb5.conf](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/krb5.conf) files according to your network setup (contact system administrators and/or your application developers for more details)

You can find more information on the concept of bypassing Kerberos login challenge in JMeter test in the [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article

Comment: Can i get NTML settings. I have tried to NTML but not able to authenticate users.